# Using client credentials with a Cognito Authorizer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to add authorization to my API Gateway. I'm not interested in authorizing users, only the app client itself. I've created a Cognito Authorizer in API Gateway and have set it to use a user pool I've created.

Using my `client_id` and `client_secret` I've been generated a bearer token from the `/oauth2/token` endpoint. But when I pass it in to the Cognito Authorizer when trying to test it, it returns `Unauthorized request: [GUID]`.

It's unclear to me why it's failing and I don't want to authorize users since I purposefully have no user login.